# CSS: Want Position: Sticky to Place Element at Bottom/Right of its Parent Container

Tags: css, css-position

Please see this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2g80r8br/11/).

I want the `<div>` with innerText "Hi!" to always appear at the **bottom/right** of the visible portion of its containing parent.  It should not scroll with the contents of its parent.

HTML:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 90%">Header 1</th>
      <th style="width: 10%">Header 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="flex-div">
          <div class="flex-item">1</div>
          <div class="flex-item">2</div>
          <div class="flex-item">3</div>
          <div class="sticky-bottom-right">Hi!</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>more</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The CSS:

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#flex-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  overflow: auto;
  positiom: relative;
}

.flex-item {
  background-color: beige;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 30 px;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 200px;
}
.sticky-bottom-right {
  font-weight: bold;
  position: sticky;
  right: 0;
}
```

I tried position: fixed, but it is relative to the entire viewport and not the containing parent.

Comment: you can use pseudo class :after or :before to parent if you dont have to click on the div.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

If you use position: absolute on .sticky-bottom-right it will be absolute to the div it's inside with the position: relative.

You also have a typo, positiom instead of position.

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#flex-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.flex-item {
  background-color: beige;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 30 px;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 200px;
}
.sticky-bottom-right {
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
  <th style="width: 90%">Header 1</th>
  <th style="width: 10%">Header 2</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="flex-div">
        <div class="flex-item">1</div>
        <div class="flex-item">2</div>
        <div class="flex-item">3</div>
        <div class="sticky-bottom-right">Hi!
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>more</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I want "Hi!" tp remain motionless in that corner.  Everything else should scroll behind it.  Check out the "Rerun" button that appears in the corner when you mouse over the examples [here](https://gedd.ski/post/position-sticky/).

Comment: But the rerun is clearly positioned absolute but since your div is positioned so that it disappears when the browser gets smaller "hi" will either disappear or go over another div.

Comment: I see your point.  I have been researching for something to allow a **fixed** position **relative to the parent**.  There is a lot of discussion by people wanting this, and some of the hacks work for their needs.  Nonetheless, it all seems to come down to hacks.  Nothing per CSS specifications.

Comment: I'll will play around a bit with it when I've got some more time. Hopefully someone else can help.

Comment: Thanks for your effort.  I figured it out.  I pulled the sticky out of the flexbox and made it a sibling to the flexbox.  I wrapped the flexbox and sticky in an outer div, and I positioned the sticky as absolute, with bottom: 0 and right: 0.

Here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2g80r8br/12/).

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it by adding flex to the parent

Got a working example [here](https://codepen.io/Arthur-Medeiros-the-lessful/pen/poQKeXz)

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  
  .parent-container {    
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    
    .sticky-item {
      width: 35px;
      height: 35px;
      background: blue;
      position: sticky;
      bottom: 0px;
    } 
  }
}
```